# Kafka merge two messages

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm new in kafka, I have this topology:[image]:

The producer produce strings. The nodes A and B, through two state store, elaborate and return new string( for example A return a1,a2 etc, B return b1,b2 etc.) into two intermediate topic. I want that the node C reads this two topic as they fill up and produce the string a1b1, a2b2. a3b3 etc. Is it possible to do it? How?

Comment: You need keys for the data and then [join the stream](https://kafka.apache.org/28/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api#joining)

Comment: Ah ok, I'll try it.Thank you.